# Run a macro when a specific workbook opens

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my situation: I have workbook "MyWorkbook" open, with a macro called "MyMacro", which is set to run on a button click, ,which I user after I download and open a file called "Analysis.xls".

Is there a way to make "MyMacro" run whenever I open a file called "Analysis.xls" without having to click a button or manually calling the macro into action?

Comment: You can run macros on the [WorkbookOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196215%28v=office.14%29.aspx) event.

Comment: I realize that, but I want the macro in "MyWorkbook" to run when I open "Analysis", not for it to run when I open "MyWorkbook".

Comment: Create an add-in and have it run on the WorkbookOpen event, tell it to check the workbook name and if its Analysis then call the macro.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (do this in a Class Module or ThisWorkbook in MyWorkbook)...

```
Private WithEvents app As Application
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set app = Application
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb as Workbook)
  If Wb.Name = "Analysis.xls" Then
    'run your macro here
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So I just paste that in a Class Module? Or should I place different things on a separate module?

Comment: Nevermind, did a little research on class modules and found an answer here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx